# Django views function without return value

Tags: python, django, fetch

I want to send information back-end via JS to update the database based on user response, but I don't need a JSON response or other HTTP rendering done.
It's a test type app so all I'm sending back is a single identifier (integer) and boolean value to indicate pass/fail on their response.

Currently I am using a fetch(`url/${identifier}/bool`) and all works as intended with the data management, but Python/Django throws an error as I am not returning any value.

So I have two questions.

1. Is fetch the right way of doing this as I am not actually expecting a response and I am doing no manipulation JS side with the data after calling it.
2. How can I stop Django from expecting a response on this as I intend to run the call as a simple function rather than an API call with JSON response sent back.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue by simply using

```
return HttpResponse(status = 200)
```